# typescript-eslint/naming-conventions function not being applied?

Tags: eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

Given my .eslintrc.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    createDefaultProgram: true,
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      // See https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1396#issuecomment-575727774 for line below
      node: {},
      typescript: {},
    },
    'import/parsers': {
      '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
  },
  rules: {
     // https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md
    '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': [
      'error',
      {
        selector: 'default',
        format: ['camelCase'],
      },
      // destructured variables come from other places so no format is enforced
      {
        selector: 'variable',
        modifiers: ['destructured'],
        format: null,
      },
      // functions defined as constants must be constants (not var/let)
      {
        selector: 'variable',
        types: ['function'],
        modifiers: ['const'],
        format: ['camelCase', 'PascalCase'],
      },
      // Constants can also be camelCase apart from UPPER_CASE
      {
        selector: 'variable',
        modifiers: ['const'],
        format: ['UPPER_CASE', 'camelCase'],
      },
      // functions can be:
      // - regular functions (camelCase)
      // - functional components (PascalCase)
      {
        selector: 'function',
        format: ['camelCase', 'PascalCase'],
      },
      // type definitions (class, interface, typeAlias, enum, typeParameter)
      // should be PascalCase
      {
        selector: 'typeLike',
        format: ['PascalCase'],
      },
      // each member of an enum (const-like) should be UPPER_CASE
      {
        selector: 'enumMember',
        format: ['UPPER_CASE'],
      },
      {
        // Ignore properties that require quotes
        selector: [
          'classProperty',
          'objectLiteralProperty',
          'typeProperty',
          'classMethod',
          'objectLiteralMethod',
          'typeMethod',
          'accessor',
          'enumMember',
        ],
        format: null,
        modifiers: ['requiresQuotes'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I think it should detect as errors UPPER_CASE named functions, but it doesn't

```
function FUNCTION1() {
  // this function name should be an error but it isn't
}

const FUNCTION2 = () => {}; // this should be an error too

const function3 = () => {}; // this should be ok

function4() {} // this should be ok too
```

Am I missing anything in this config?

Answer (score 0):

One of those is easy, in `const FUNCTION2 = () => {};`, `FUNCTION2` is actually a variable, and const.

Helpful tip: you can use error messages to your advantage by forcing a failure condition to see which one it's matching.  Adding `custom: { regex: 'FUNCTION2', match: false}` to that rule adds the caveat "but it can't match FUNCTION2" to it, which will turn that line into the error:

> Variable name `FUNCTION2` must not match the RegExp: /FUNCTION2/u

which exposes that it's a variable.

Doing that one rule at a time for `FUNCTION1` will at least tell you which rule it's matching.